# How to disable and enable a click event on a button in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#

I have a form with 10 buttons.

When I click any of the buttons, it should be **disabled** so that I can't click on it again, but it should be re-**enabled** again when I click on any other button.

I know there is a way to do it, disabling and enabling the control (button) but I don't want to use this method because I want to change the colour of the button when it is in use (when its clicked), and if the button gets disable it will get its original colour.

So I want to know if there is a way to do it. Thanks

Comment: @JohnB I tried to remove the event from the click event in the button i click and then add the event methd again when i click another button. The problem is that the way I'm doing it right now is to remove only the event on the button that it's being click and adding the event on all the others buttons. That way the event method it's added multiple times on one each button

Comment: I believe what @JohnB is asking is that you post your code so that we can guide/help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way to do it.

```
bool[] buttons = new bool[10];

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (buttons[0])
     {
         // Code.....

         buttonToggle(0);

         // Here I change the color based on the estate of the correspondent bool variable
     }
}

private void buttonToggle(int btn)
{
    buttons[btn] = false;

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if (i != btn)
        {
            buttons[i] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks @TheGeneral for the idea

Answer (score 2):

Just use a variable

```
private bool isClicking = false;

public void SomeEvent()
{
   if (isClicking) return;
   try
   {
      isClicking = true;
      // do some codes
   }
   finally
   {
      isClicking = false;
   }
}
```

Though in truth, the usual course of events for this situation is you disable your button not color it

Comment: Personally I prefer to name this variable `lockEvents`.

Answer (score 0):

@JohnB @DaniDev

This is the code I'm using

```
bool btn1,btn2,btn3;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     AvtivateButtons(1,btn1);
}

private void ActivateButtons(int btn, bool btnState)
{

            switch (btn)
            {
                case 1:
                    button1.Click -= button1_Click;
                    btnEstate = false;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    button2.Click -= button2_Click;
                    btnEstate = false;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    button3.Click -= button3_Click;
                    btnEstate = false;
                    break;
            }

            if (!btn1)
            {
                button1.Click += button1_Click;
            }
            if (!btn2)
            {
                button2.Click += button2_Click;
            }
            if (!btn3)
            {
                button3.Click += button3_Click;
            }


            btnState = true;

}
```

Comment: @CoderJoe sorry, I didnt think on that.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a javascript method to return true or false. When a javascript method returns false, the post back will be skipped.

```
<asp:Button ID="mybutton" OnClientClick="return JS_Method();" OnClick="PostBackMethod_Click" />
```